# error when fetching data from coredata :thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data

I'm building a project that using coredata to save data and then fetch them to display. 
I have `AddingVC` to add the information of students . And the `ListVC` to display them in tableview 
.
the error happened in the `ListVC.swift` when I call the func `getListStudentFromLocalDB()` in `viewWillAppear` to display the data that I fetch from the core data, the xcode reports an error :
 `thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0)` 
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`.
this is the error code in ListVC : 
`override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
        self.getListStudentFromLocalDB()
    }`

I spent my day to solve this problem but I have not finished it yet. I attach my project file in that topic, so please download it, and try to run it then please help me how to solve this bug 
:(  this is the download link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzwvVCINDlUCckUzc1dVMjFYWUE/view?usp=sharing . 
I use AERecord library to do this project , so when you download it, please run `pod install` in terminal please. Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code that causes this error.

Comment: @TomHarrington I edited .

Comment: That still doesn't make it clear which specific line of code causes the error.

Comment: it's locate on 50th line of ListViewController.swift , thanks for reply